# How to get client's IP after SSL handshake in OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

The problem is that after doing this:

```
    SSL* ssl;
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock);
    int err = SSL_accept(ssl);
```

I can't get acces to client's socket 'sock', so I neither can get acces to client's IP.
Is there anyway I can get it from SSL structure? Couldn't find that at docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no information about IP in the SSL structure and you can use SSL even without any IP address. You will find the necessary information with `getpeername` on the socket itself. In case you need to get the socket for the SSL object use `SSL_get_fd`.